# htaccess - loading url with 'www' on first load

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site that I need to load with 'www' on the first load.

I have multiple versions of my site on different subdomains.

- dev.example.com (for development)
- testing.example.com (for testing)
- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (live production version)

In my htaccess file I have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

In my HTML on the live version I have set the `<base>` tag to include 'https://www' so when someone navigates around it will automatically go to 'www'.

It automatically loads with SSL and in chrome it will redirect to 'www' but in firefox on first load it does not include 'www'.

I need it to include 'www' on first load for use with an API using CORS config that must include 'www'.

Comment: ok so done some more testing it works in chrome and uc browser but not in firefox, opera, edge or safari (the last version available for windows anyway)

Comment: The behavior of the _server_ is independent from the behavior of specific _clients_ ...